# Which of the following reaction will have greater enthalpy and why?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

> Which of the following reaction will have greater enthalpy and why?
>
> $\ce{C (g) + 4 H (g) -> CH4(g)}$ (reaction enthalpy = $x\ \mathrm{kJ/mol}$)
>
> $\ce{C (graphite) + 2H2 (g) -> CH4 (g)}$ (reaction enthalpy = $y\ \mathrm{kJ/mol}$)

I thought that since $\ce{H2}$ is in its aggregation state it would have enthalpy of $0\ \mathrm{kJ/mol}$ and hence $y\gt x$.

Comment: The first reaction is the most exothermic rection

Comment: Could you complete your argument? If you compare two things, you need to make statements about both to be able to compare them. As it stands, it is not clear why you conclude that y > x.

Answer (score 1):

Maurice has stated why equation **1** is much more exothermic than equation **2**. A visualization of the processes may help you understand the details. Equation **1** involves the reaction of a carbon atom with four atoms of hydrogen to form methane in the gas phase. The bond dissociation energy (BDE) of the hydrogen molecule is +104 kcal/mol. Accordingly, the heat of formation (ΔH<sub>f</sub><sup>o</sup>) of the hydrogen atom is half this value or +52 kcal/mol. The ΔH<sub>f</sub><sup>o</sup> of the carbon atom from graphite is +171 kcal/mol. Both hydrogen and graphite are taken as 0 kcal/mol at the Standard State. The right hand side of the chart shows that the sum total of the necessary atoms is +379 kcal/mol above the Standard State. This is your starting point for equation **1**. To form methane in the gas phase the reaction will be exothermic by -379 kcal/mol plus the ΔH<sub>f</sub><sup>o</sup> of methane (-18 kcal/mol) for a total of -397 kcal/mol for equation **1**. On the other hand, equation **2** is nothing more than the ΔH<sub>f</sub><sup>o</sup> of methane as -18 kcal/mol below the Standard State as shown in the left hand diagram. This diagram also shows the stepwise BDE's of C-H bonds starting from methane. The same value for equation **1** is obtained, -397 kcal/mol.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The heat of formation of $CH_4$ is $-75$ kJ/mol. This is not much : *y* is small.  As the dissociation energies of $C-H$ bonds are higher than $400 kJ/mol$, the heat of reaction of the first equation is more than $1600 kJ/mol$. This first reaction is about $20$ times more exothermic than the second reaction. *x* >> *y* !!